# Refile: Image links lost after deployment with Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano3, refile

I have tried to add `attachments` to linked directories in my `deploy.rb`, but the links to images still vanish after every deploy on Linode.

What should I do to keep image links after deployment?

Comment: Do the images in the attachments directory still exist, or is your deploy overwriting it?

Comment: After deploy images in `tmp/uploads/store` vanish. Which made me think about including `tmp/uploads/store` and `tmp/uploads/cache` in `linked_dirs` in my `deploy.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with vanishing assets is solved, credits goes to [@wkurosawa](https://github.com/wkurosawa), he was so kind to help me with [this issue](https://github.com/refile/refile/issues/463). Just have to add `tmp/uploads/cache` and `tmp/uploads/store` to `linked_dirs` in `deploy.rb`.